# How to get the sunrise/ sunset time for remote location in their timezone, not device timezone when using open weather api, in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, timezone-offset, openweathermap

I am getting the sunrise/sunset time but it is in the timezone that my device is using. For example, I am in New York, when I look up cities that are in EST, it returns the sunrise/sunset time in the right timezone. But if I look up Dubai, the hours are off. The sunset time returned for Dubai is 10:57PM. Which is the time in New York(EST) when the sun sets in Dubai.

Here is my OpenWeatherAPI response-

```
base = stations;
    clouds =     {
        all = 20;
    };
    cod = 200;
    coord =     {
        lat = "25.27";
        lon = "55.3";
    };
    dt = 1565620936;
    id = 292223;
    main =     {
        humidity = 71;
        pressure = 995;
        temp = 36;
        "temp_max" = 36;
        "temp_min" = 36;
    };
    name = Dubai;
    sys =     {
        country = AE;
        id = 7537;
        message = "0.0067";
        sunrise = 1565574654;
        sunset = 1565621827;
        type = 1;
    };
    timezone = 14400;
    visibility = 7000;
    weather =     (
                {
            description = "few clouds";
            icon = 02d;
            id = 801;
            main = Clouds;
        }
    );
    wind =     {
        deg = 340;
        speed = "4.6";
    };
```

How do I get the sunrise/sunset time in the remote time zone that I am querying in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, this is how you do it-

You use the `timezone` field returned in the API response and set it as the offset.

```
   double offset =  [json[@"timezone"]doubleValue]; //getting timezone offset

   double sunriseTimestampval =  [json[@"sys"][@"sunrise"]doubleValue];

   NSTimeInterval sunriseTimestamp = (NSTimeInterval)sunriseTimestampval;
   NSDate* sunriseDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sunriseTimestamp];

   NSDateFormatter *sunriseDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [sunriseDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
   [sunriseDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:offset]];//->Converting to remote timezone

 NSString *sunriseTime = [sunriseDateFormatter stringFromDate:sunriseDate];
```